# Pandas .resample() creates dates that weren't present in the original Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, resampling

I am trying to resample Data Frame from daily to monthly frequencies. The last date of my original Data Frame is `2020-03-17`. [Original Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msYyP.png). I'm doing the resampling in the following way: `df.resample('M').mean()`. As a result I obtain the Data Frame with dates up to `2020-12-31`, so basically resampling adds more than a half a year of nonexistent dates. [Data Frame after resampling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcnBH.png) I tried to play around with parameters "closed" and "label" but didn't achieve any success. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you need remove missing values after `resample` ? by `df.dropna()` ?

Comment: No, I don't have missing values there. I just want to have 2020-03 as a last month of the Data Frame after resampling, as I do have so in my original df. But what I get is 2020-12 -  resampling somehow goes into the future.

Comment: hmmm, what is maximum value of index? `print (df.index.max())` Maybe DatetimeIndex is not sorted.

Comment: Timestamp('2020-12-03 00:00:00')

Comment: yes, so if maximum value is december, it is expected.

Comment: if it should be `12 March` problem is in converting datetimes

Comment: Oh indeed, now I see, that something wrong is with original index! I should definitely investigate this! Thanks!